# Basic shape transformation library

Tags: library, drawing

The use case is to do some visualization based on some given input. To do this I'm looking for a library that's easy to incorporate in my application. This application will be written in .NET so C# or JavaScript based libraries are both valid options. The library needs to be able to

- Draw a cylinder based on at least a radius
- Draw an object subtracting a cylinder shape
- Rotate these objects in 3D space
- Create a flat view of the result (no 3D view necessary)

Then I have to figure out how I can visualize the intersection and gaps of various objects.

Most experience I have is with management information systems (although I once did some things with blender3d and a 3d engine). It would be nice if the library is simple, Easy to learn, open-source, and/or well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**: You can use three.js in C# with SharpKit. Read more about that [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Using-three.js-in-C%23-with-SharpKit).

<strike>I can't fulfill your requirements. You need both of C# and JavaScript libraries. But, I can only give you a JavaScript library. I hope you can make this as the alternative one.</strike>

---

I would suggest using **[three.js](http://threejs.org/)**.

> **three.js** is JavaScript 3D Library. The aim of the project is to create a lightweight 3D library with a very low level of complexity — in other words, for dummies. The library provides `<canvas>`, `<svg>`, CSS3D and WebGL renderers. Taken from this [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/#javascript-3d-library).

What three.js can do? Based on your requirement, it has answer:

- Draw a cylinder based on at least a radius, you can make a cylinder geometry. There is one up to eight arguments to take. (an example is given [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/CylinderGeometry)).
- Draw an object subtracting a cylinder shape, you can do this with additional library. The library is called as **[csg.js](https://github.com/evanw/csg.js/)**. [Tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/) and [the result](http://learningthreejs.com/data/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/) are given.
- Rotate these objects in 3D space, you can do it with [rotation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Euler) or using some mathematics functions, like matrix and soon. There is tutorial out there.
- Create a flat view of the result (no 3D view necessary), it's about [camera](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/Camera).

If you have enough time, please read this full documentation [here](http://threejs.org/docs/).

Like I said before, I hope this library is what you need. <strike>I have no idea about C#. I am pretty sure that somebody will answer about it soon, though.</strike>

Comment: Thanks, I only need one of the two. When I'm going with the JS option I'll integrate it in an asp.net web application. No JS <-> C# tricks necessary.

Comment: OK. Ah, you're right, you can embed JavaScript into ASP.NET application. I missed about that.

Answer (score 2):

I think [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) might fit the bill.

It isn't actually a library, but more like a compiler; it takes a scene definition file, parses it, loads it, and displays it. See the [about page](http://www.openscad.org/about.html) if you really want a library.

Your requirements can mostly be found on the [cheat sheet](http://www.openscad.org/cheatsheet/index.html).

- draw a cylinder: ✔ use the [cylinder command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids#cylinder)
- draw an object subtracting a cylinder shape: ✔ use the [difference operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/CSG_Modelling#difference)
- rotate these objects in 3D space: ✔ use [rotate](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#rotate)
- create a flat view of the result: ✔ you can do a [3D-to-2D projection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_the_2D_Subsystem#3D_to_2D_Projection); also, while I'm not familiar with the software, I'd be very surprised indeed if you couldn't get an orthographic view of your model

[OpenJSCad](http://openjscad.org/) looks to be very similar, but is an interactive web application.

Comment: Both seem nice Cad solutions, but aren't libraries.